# Unable to create a pfSense VM for azure from the portal

Tags: azure, pfsense

We are trying to create a pfSense VM for azure. We can select the pfSense product and we can begin creating a VM for it. However when we reach the part where we need to select which size we want to pick for the machine, all the options are greyed out with "Not Available" showing. There isn't even a single size available to choose.

[image]

We've tried doing this on both a Bizspark subscription, as well as a pay as you go subscription. Neither of which show any difference. We also tried choosing SSD instead of HDD, as well as trying out different regions, but all yielded the same result. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Could you create other type VMs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that pfSense is not active in your subscription. Please contact the Azure billing support to have this enabled for you.  You could try to create a support ticket on Azure Portal. More information please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/sku-series-unavailable). Please note that billing support is free.

**Notes: pfSense in Azure is a third-party service. You can't use monthly free credits for external services.** More information about understand your Azure external service charges please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-your-azure-marketplace-charges).